# What SRID is this?

Tags: coordinate-system, srid

I have been sent the following coordinates, they belong to Switzerland:

> 641.621 189.131

I need to convert those to EPGS:4326, but I don't know what the source SRID is.

Does someone recognise the coordinate system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There could be two possibilities. If the coordinates are in km and is the top of a ridgeline/mountain (approximately lat:46.853795 lon:7.985557), the CRS could be CH1903 / LV03, EPSG::21781.

If the coordinates are in meters and using CH1903 / LV03C-G (EPSG::21782), they're near Greyerzstrasse in Berne as Joseph suggested. However. EPSG states that 21782 is only used in Liechtenstein.

Answer (score 6):

I've found a couple of useful tools to find possible CRSes if you know the general area.

[epsg.io](https://epsg.io/) : this is a web site which is a search engine for CRSes. Type in something like 'Switzerland' and it'll list possible matching CRSes. You can also see the CRS extent on a map and see metadata in various formats (proj4, WKT etc) so you can check that units and accuracy are suitable.

A few months back they also added a feature to project coordinates so you can check to see if the results look sensible (it helps if you know some reference points).

[Projestions (QGIS plugin)](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Projestions/) . If you use QGIS, this plugin lets you search using the current canvas extent for CRSes whose bounds intersect. You can zoom in (perhaps using a web basemap) to an area of interest and list coordinate systems which intersect this area.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps `CH1903 / LV03C-G` (aka `EPSG:21782`)?

[image]